# Counting groups with combined scores of 10

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose that a math class has $24$ students, and the scores on a recent test are $\{1=\text{poor}, 2=\text{basic}, 3=\text{proficient}, 4=\text{excellent}\}$. The number of students in each score category is the same.  If the students line up for class the next day, how many lines are there such that the teacher can split up the line of students in groups (not necessarily the same size) with a combined score of $10$ without rearranging the line?

---

Basically, we want to count the number of permutations of $a=(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)$ such that there are partial sums $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i$ of values $10,20,30,40,50$ and $60$. Since the total combined score of the students is $60$, it is automatically a partial sum

For example, $a$ is already a valid line because we have partial sums of $(1,3,6,10,11,13,16,20,...60)$ and $10,20,30,40,50,60$ occur in this sequence.

Another harder-to-detect example would be $(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1)$ since we can split the line as $( [1, 2, 2, 3, 2], [4, 1, 1, 2, 2], [4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 1, 1], [3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3, 1] )$.

If we had something like $(4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, then it would not be a valid line because the partial sums are $(4,8,12,16,20,24,....60)$ but $10$ does not occur as a partial sum for this sequence.

Comment: What is meant by "uneven" groups?

Comment: Not necessarily the same size

Comment: What does the constraint "without rearranging the line" mean?

Comment: It is interpreted as the line being a permutation where the order matters...

Comment: I would suggest changing the question to state that the groups are not necessarily the same size since uneven groups suggests that they cannot be the same size.

Comment: The multinomial (24;6,6,6,6) is the number of strings to check, about 2.3 trillion. I don't know how long to check each string, nor whether 2.3 trillion is too many for some fast language to handle. If anyone knows about this I'd appreciate a comment.

Comment: Using a recursive procedure implemented in Maple (runtime about one second), there are exactly $20448394596$ qualifying arrangements.

Comment: I would think that is quite cumbersome to find.   We know that each group will contain at least 3 students and at most 8 students.  Hence, if we know that we can split up the line into $k$ groups of $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_k$ students, then there are $a_1!a_2!a_3!...a_k!$ arrangements for a specific order of permutations.

Comment: @quasi did you use a brute force approach?

Comment: @J. Linne: Yes, brute force, but recursive.

Comment: @quasi Your approach can be formalised through generating functions; see my answer.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine all integer solutions to $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=10$ where $0\le x_i\le6$, corresponding to *partitions* of $10$ into parts of size $1,2,3,4$ with at most $6$ of each part. Any admissible permutation of the student scores splits into six parts, each with sum $10$ and being an ordering of some partition of the kind previously described. To each solution $(x_i)$ associate the monomial
$$\binom{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4}t^{x_1}u^{x_2}v^{x_3}w^{x_4}$$
and add the monomials up. The resulting polynomial $A$ is the generating function for the *ordered partitions* of $10$ into parts of size $1,2,3,4$ with at most $6$ of each part.

The desired number is then simply the $(tuvw)^6$ coefficient of $A^6$, which is $20448394596$. [The following Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##JY7BaoNAFEX3fsUDISR12mgiriIIhUALzUZXGSZg0mf6YJwJOpFXgvl1O9LlvYtzTlu7H2xrR5d6mpghh6o@a5QsSQl4kEhHFRz9XVo9oHywTFS0YblR0ZblVkUpy1RBnkMSj89PS@b5D4h3@bDLM88YBPPoYcwCDtYc8Op1A34Yh1fsehX0Vvfe4O3rNzgGDs08K@tqLZdfd@3I2JZqXRQhvEBFLfZFsWQ@hStYrGBdwExQwd7qb7m/a11Se9PU/MoSO8L@3WLT0IXQOBkmvijciFhko1ILAbPtlM11apqm11tHxv0B) computes this:

```
xx = Table[x[i], {i,4}]
Z = Solve[{x[1]+2x[2]+3x[3]+4x[4] == 10}~Join~Table[0<=v<=6, {v,xx}], xx, NonNegativeIntegers]
sols = xx /. Z
tens = Total[(Multinomial@@# * Times@@(xx^#) &) /@ sols]
Fold[FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[#1, {#2,0,6}]]&, tens^6, xx]
```